# Toolbar overlapping with Label of a component

Tags: codenameone

I have enabled and set the Toolbar for a Form. The Form has a TextArea Component with a Label set, functioning as a title. The Label is not shown when navigating to that screen. I presume it is overlapped. Is this the case? What am I missing?
Global setting for Toolbar is set to false.

```java
    Form aFrm = new Form("aTitle", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    //Set up the toolbar using a static utility method.
    GGUtil.setTheAppToolbar(aFrm);        
    //Create a TextArea to display the information from a Resource file.
    TextArea aTxtArea = new TextArea(GGUtil.openResourceFileToString(null, "/atextfile.txt"));
    //Signal virtual keyboard whether editing is allowed.
    aTxtArea.setConstraint(TextArea.UNEDITABLE);
    //Disable editing.
    aTxtArea.setEditable(false);
    //Grow in rows to display the content
    aTxtArea.setGrowByContent(true);
    //Create and set the text of the Label
    Label txtAreaLabel = new Label("labelTitle");
    //Set the Label for the TextArea
    aTxtArea.setLabelForComponent(txtAreaLabel);
    //Add the TextArea to the Form.
    aFrm.add(aTxtArea);
    ...
```

Follows the code for the static utility method that sets the Toolbar.

```java
    //Create a Toolbar obj for this Form.
    Toolbar appToolbar = new Toolbar();
    //Enable Toolbar for this Form only, setting the tile at the moment.
    aForm.setToolbar(appToolbar);
    //Set the title of the Toolbar.
    appToolbar.setTitle("Toolbar Title");
    //Create Container to hold "sandwich" menu options.
    Form sandwichMenu = new Form("Settings", new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    //Center the Toolbar
    appToolbar.setTitleCentered(true);
    //Create and add a "Close" button using another static utility method.
    GGUtil.addCloseRightSettings(appToolbar, sandwichMenu, "Close");
    //Add the "Settings" Form in the "sandwich" menu option.
    appToolbar.addComponentToRightSideMenu(sandwichMenu);
    ...
```

[Simulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3HaD.jpg)

Comment: Can you add a minimal example code to the question, reproducing the problem? Can you add a screenshot as well?

Comment: @FrancescoGalgani Please, check it out now.

Comment: I've just added an answer

Answer (score 1):

The `setLabelForComponent` method it is not designed to add a title to a TextArea. I'm not sure what its actual usefulness is, however, looking at its implementation (found here: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/Component.java), it looks like its use is limited to something involving tickering (as far as I know, tickering only makes sense with Labels and Buttons). Honestly I've never used `setLabelForComponent`.

If you want to add a text above the TextArea with title function, simply add it to the form before TextArea with `aFrom.add(txtAreaLabel)` and style it with CSS.

Comment: Well I was reading the Codename One Javadoc and the description for setLabelForComponent is: "Allows us to indicate the label associated with this component thus providing visual feedback related for this component e.g. starting the ticker when the component receives focus."

In any case, I will give up this approach since it seems destined for other usage, although conflicting.
Thank you.

Comment: By the way, the Form has already a title set, since there was a String argument passed in the Form Constructor. How come it does not show up either?
We have to resort to the Label solution because that does not work either...

Comment: This is a method that's similar to one in Swing e.g. if you're in a form we can't start tickering all the labels as it will look weird and noisy. It's also important for accessibility e.g. when you focus the text area you want the screen reader to read that label. However, we can't add it to the form ourselves since we don't know the layout and don't know where you might want it (left, top, bottom etc.). So this is just a hint to the GUI

Comment: Dear @ShaiAlmog, thank you for clarifying the issue with the `Form` title.

Comment: Great. FYI if the answer is correct you should accept it which gives both you and Francesco points. These are helpful for doing more things on stack overflow...